# Send List of Custom model between Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've found lots of answers on SO but none working for me.
I have a `List<MyModel> myList` that I want to pass and retrieve through Intents.
MyModel implements Parcelable and its implementation.
I am using `intent.putExtra("my_key",(Parcelable) myList);`
At runtime it throws the exception

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable

And if I use `putParcelableArrayListExtra` then it says wrong second argument type.
Any explaination or other way would be helpful
EDIT: My Model class is :

```
public class Filter {

    private String categoryId;

    public List<PrimaryFilterData> getPrimaryFilterDataList() {
        return primaryFilterDataList;
    }

    public void setPrimaryFilterDataList(List<PrimaryFilterData> primaryFilterDataList) {
        this.primaryFilterDataList = primaryFilterDataList;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    private String categoryName;

    private List<PrimaryFilterData> primaryFilterDataList;


    public static class PrimaryFilterData implements Parcelable
    {
        private String filterId;

        protected PrimaryFilterData(Parcel in) {
            filterId = in.readString();
            filterName = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(filterId);
            dest.writeString(filterName);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public static final Creator<PrimaryFilterData> CREATOR = new Creator<PrimaryFilterData>() {
            @Override
            public PrimaryFilterData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new PrimaryFilterData(in);
            }

            @Override
            public PrimaryFilterData[] newArray(int size) {
                return new PrimaryFilterData[size];
            }
        };

        public String getFilterName() {
            return filterName;
        }

        public void setFilterName(String filterName) {
            this.filterName = filterName;
        }

        public String getFilterId() {
            return filterId;
        }

        public void setFilterId(String filterId) {
            this.filterId = filterId;
        }

        public List<SecondaryFilterData> getSecondaryFilterDataList() {
            return secondaryFilterDataList;
        }

        public void setSecondaryFilterDataList(List<SecondaryFilterData> secondaryFilterDataList) {
            this.secondaryFilterDataList = secondaryFilterDataList;
        }

        private String filterName;

        private List<SecondaryFilterData> secondaryFilterDataList;

    }

    public static class SecondaryFilterData implements Parcelable {
        private String secFilterName;
        private String secFilterId;
        private boolean isChecked=false;

        public SecondaryFilterData(){}

        protected SecondaryFilterData(Parcel in) {
            secFilterName = in.readString();
            secFilterId = in.readString();
            isChecked = in.readByte() != 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(secFilterName);
            dest.writeString(secFilterId);
            dest.writeByte((byte) (isChecked ? 1 : 0));
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public static final Creator<SecondaryFilterData> CREATOR = new Creator<SecondaryFilterData>() {
            @Override
            public SecondaryFilterData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SecondaryFilterData(in);
            }

            @Override
            public SecondaryFilterData[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SecondaryFilterData[size];
            }
        };

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return isChecked;
        }

        public void setIsChecked(boolean isChecked) {
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
        }

        public String getSecFilterName() {
            return secFilterName;
        }

        public void setSecFilterName(String secFilterName) {
            this.secFilterName = secFilterName;
        }

        public String getSecFilterId() {
            return secFilterId;
        }

        public void setSecFilterId(String secFilterId) {
            this.secFilterId = secFilterId;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I wish to send list of Primary data from one activity to other

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Comment: sounds like something wrong with the parameters sequence. Post parcelable class

Comment: @Shahzeb I have done the parcel implementation by clicking on Android Studio option which automatically writes the required method. You mean to say the problem in that??

Comment: Use serialisable or parcealable to send custom data model using intent.all the elements should be serialisable then

Comment: if you want to use putParcelableArrayListExtra then your myList type should be of ArrayList instead of List. So change data type of myList to ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew!
After long hours of work; I come to following conculsion (I'll update answer if I find some better reason).
**Parceble/Serializablwe is passing value of list as reference; that's why when I was trying to access that list from other activity; it was returning null.**
Currently ; I have maintained a global list(singleton using application class) and updating / retreiving it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a `Bundle`.

```
// Important - use array list not regular list.
// MyModel must implement Parcelable
ArrayList<MyModel> myList;

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("my_key", myList);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

If your list must be of type `List` you can convert it at the last minute.

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("my_key", new ArrayList<MyModel>(myList));
```

Then in the receiving activity.

```
List<MyModel> myList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("my_key");
```

Comment: Thanks but this is showing the second type of error that I mentioned above; wrong second argument type

Comment: @GDroid Does `MyModel` implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: Yes and also its implementations

Comment: All is good except that I am not receiving the list in the intent inside receiving activity

Comment: @GDroid you must be doing something wrong in your code. This method works perfectly. I just created an app now to test it and had no troubles. The data made it through the intent. Check that you are using the same key and that the list you pass in is not empty.

Comment: @GDroid Your parcelables are probably fine. I meant your code for populating the array, building the intent, reading from the intent, etc.

Comment: For reading and writing I am using the codes as provided in this question's answers and data is there in list; I,ve checked using debugger

Answer (score 1):

if your `MyModel` class contains data memeber of only primary or `String` type then

1. Implement `java.io.Serializable` interface in your `MyModel` class.
2. Use `Intent.putExtra(String name, Serializable value)` method to send the list of model with Intent.
3. `Intent.getSerializableExtra(String name)` to retrieve list back;

Comment: Thanks for answer @akhilesh but my class contains a list of another type model and other data. And using serializable is not recommended I guess

Comment: just make other class type data member `Serializable` also

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your List does indeed not implement Parcelable. Its content does.  Try to pass an array, not a List, of Parcelables:

```
intent.putExtra("my_key", myList.toArray());
```

Edit: I just saw that it is also possible to send lists but they have to be of type ArrayList. If you don't want to convert your List to an array, try to declare your List as `ArrayList<MyModel> myList` where MyModel must implement Parcelable.

Comment: yes this removed the error but I am not getting any data when try to retreive. .

Comment: Then please add your send and receive code in your Question so we can have a look.

Comment: I changed the type to array list ; things looked fine but it didnt work as while retrieving I am getting null

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your java object as a Parcelable object in the bundle. But before that you need your **model java class to implement Parcelable interface** and override the necessary methods.

Once you have implemented the Parcelable interface you can easily pass your model class(java class) object as Parcelable to the bundle. Small snippet below:

```
yourBundle.putParcelable(YOUR_OBJ_KEY,yourModelObject);
```

Here, yourModelObject is the object of your model class that contains all the getters and setters method that you can use.

The point i am trying to make is that you pass your entire java object to the next activity rather than the list. By doing this you will get all the information that you require in your next activity inside this java object.

Comment: Thanks for answet but if I have a list of 100 objects then you wish me to send only one?

Comment: Why would you have a 100 list of objects of the same MyModel type? When you can have all your data in a single object. Please, if you can show me your model structure.